# I fixed a bug in code and 3 people marked my edit as rejected

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5525246

With the code prior to my edit, "new Date("xx").toISOString()" produces "NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaN.NZ"

That's clearly never the desire behavior. The behavior of a shim should be to mimic the native functions behavior.

Does anyone know why this edit was rejected?

edit: While I'm asking, [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5142529) clearly fixed syntax errors in the code but was also rejected...

Comment: You needed more plagiarism and use of backticks for it to be approved

Comment: You might want to be more careful editing...1 approved to 10 rejected might land you an editing timeout soon.

Comment: Do not edit code. Period. If you have better code, post new answer. If you see glaring error, comment and let the author fix it.

Comment: I was never checking if my edits were approved before. It's surprising I can be placed in "timeout" for fixing syntax errors in code. Can anyone provide a link to an information page that describes why my edits are inappropriate?

Comment: They're inappropriate because you're changing the intent of the answer. If the answer contains a code error, either comment to the poster and tell them so they can fix it, or downvote the answer for being wrong and post your own correct answer. If you change the poster's code incorrectly, it's *their* reputation that's negatively affected, and it can possibly negatively affect their entire account (such as suspension for too many negatively-voted answers). The general rule: Don't edit code except for formatting.

Comment: [Your edits are appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225121/pretty-sure-that-my-edit-was-correct-but-it-was-rejected/225389#225389), assuming you're genuinely fixing a minor bug and not introducing a different error or changing the core of the answer. Unfortunately, there are users on SO (represented in the comments here) who stand against improving content. Sorry about this. Please disregard them and keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you @Gilles and Ken-White, both of your responses make sense and represent reasons why it should and shouldn't be done. Until I have enough karma points to not require approval, I'll stick to comments, and even then, only fix syntax errors.